# How to propertly reference a namespace for Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.XmlFile.GetValue

Tags: xml, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

i want to use MSBuild to insert a custom xml element into web.config. After looking up online, i found such solution:

1) Store element in the .build file in projectextensions

```
<ProjectExtensions>
 <CustomElement name="CustomElementName">
  ...
 </CustomElement>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

2) Retrieve the element with GetValue

```
<Target name="ModifyConfig">
<XmlFile.GetValue Path="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
               XPath="Project/ProjectExtensions/CustomElement[@name='CustomElementName']">
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="CustomElementProperty"/>
</XmlFile.GetValue>
</Target>
```

**This will not work** as i need to reference a namespace the .build project is using for it to find the needed element (checked the .build file with XPath Visualizer). So, i look up for a further solution and come to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <XmlNamespace Include="MSBuild">
            <Prefix>msb</Prefix>
            <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003</Uri>
        </XmlNamespace>
</ItemGroup>

<Target name="ModifyConfig">
<XmlFile.GetValue Path="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Namespaces="$(XmlNamespace)"
               XPath="/msb:Project/msb:ProjectExtensions/msb:CustomElement[@name='CustomElementName']"
                 >
            <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="CustomElementProperty"/>
</XmlFile.GetValue>
</Target>
```

But for some reason namespace is not recognized - MSBuild reports the following error:

**C:...\mybuild.build(53,9): error : A task error has occured.
 C:...\mybuild.build(53,9): error : Message  = Namespace prefix 'msb' is not
defined.**

I tried some variations of referencing it differently but none work, and there is not much about propertly referencing those namespaces online also. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong and how to do it propertly?

Comment: Found the error - should've used @ when referencing an item from Itemgroup rather than $. So it actually should look Namespaces="@(XmlNamespace)"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a custom task from [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) called `XmlMassUpdate` for inserting a custom XML element into an xml file.

```
<XmlMassUpdate 
ContentFile="web.config" 
SubstitutionsFile="changes.xml" 
ContentRoot="/configuration/system.web" 
SubstitutionsRoot="/system.web" />
```

You can also reference the XML directly in the project file like this:

```
<XmlMassUpdate ContentFile="web.config" ContentRoot="/configuration/system.web"
    NamespaceDefinitions="msb=http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    SubstitutionsFile="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
    SubstitutionsRoot="/msb:Project/msb:ProjectExtensions/msb:system.web" />
```

However, the tile of your question seems to suggest you have problems getting XML values first not changing them. The mentioned lib does also have the `XmlQuery` task, which reads values from XML files and populates parameters based on those values.

Comment: I haven't worked with XmlMassUpdate before, but as i see from initial search it's best used for substitutions, while i need to get the element and insert it to a certain location in target document's xml hierarchy. Is that possible with XmlMassUpdate?

Comment: I would think this should be possible - yes. You could perhaps update a single tag with multiple ones?

Comment: That sounds like a solution, but i would really prefer to use Microsoft.Sdc.XMLFile.AddElement for this task. Thank you for your input mfloryan, i will try XMLMassUpdate if i won't find a way to reference namespace for GetValue propertly.